# Route53, can I choose where my DNS servers are located?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

My users and AWS servers are in Australia where Amazon supposedly has DNS servers, so I would like an AU server as my Primary nameserver, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a slave nameserver in AU on your own and then set that as one of the authoritative nameservers for your zone.

You'd need:

https://github.com/barnybug/cli53

See also:

[Dig -x equivalent for AWS Route 53](https://serverfault.com/questions/512992/dig-x-equivalent-for-aws-route-53)

Alternatively, you could simply setup a recursive caching nameserver in AU and configure all your hosts to use it for resolution.

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I am looking for, I had given up on it

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible as the name servers stored in the domain name do not have any given priority. The client will use the name server that it is given.

Comment: There's an article here: http://serverfault.com/questions/130608/when-is-a-secondary-nameserver-hit

Answer (score 0):

You can't choose the location of your name servers via Route53.

Most people have no legitimate need to do so, maybe reconsider if you actually need this.

Comment: Why is this so? If I am located in Australia and type myname.com.au my ISP's nameserver first makes a 200ms journey to the USA grabs the data then caches it. Every X minutes the ISP's DNS server would do this again. I also see that all my nameservers are in the same Amazon east area, wouldn't it be better to spread them out?

Comment: If you're checking the location using an IP locator, this does not return the true location of where the server actually is; it simply returns the location of which the IP subnet is registered/allocated. The Amazon IP addresses are routed to different servers in different regions, so they are in-fact spread out.