# AWS Route53 Replicate to thrid party name servers

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Is it possible to configure Route53 to replicate to non Amazon name servers?

Comment: This is possibly best asked on the Amazon support forums, or to your Amazon support rep - AWS is a closed system, so I would venture a guess at "no", but only Amazon themselves will be able to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Not so, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use their API to automatically retrieve the information declared on it. You can retrieve records, zone names, geoloc related info and so on. But it requires development skills though.

Answer (score 1):

I did this.

See:

[Dig -x equivalent for AWS Route 53](https://serverfault.com/questions/512992/dig-x-equivalent-for-aws-route-53)

In short, I used:

1. cli53
2. r53
3. bind9
4. h2n